FrankenPHP: How to use my own zend extension
I just found out about FrankenPHP - it's running really good so far. To make a benchmark test, i have to integrate my own PHP Zend Extension first, to see if it is viable to dig deeper into this. My PHP extension is running fine within my php-cli and php-fpm, but the FrankenPHP does not know anything of it so far.
I tried to inject my extension, when i am building the go binary - by extending one of the both flags, adding my extension module name:
CGO_CFLAGS=$(php-config --includes) CGO_LDFLAGS="$(php-config --ldflags) $(php-config --libs)" go build

Unfortunately i cannot find anything in the documentations - rather than doing a static build, which is nothing i need right now.
The extension itself is based on C and is using mpfr, so i may end up adding the functionality into my go module and expose it - with the upcoming challenge to call it in php, but i think that does not sound right at all. I'd prefer to compile it into the binary, just like opcache / gmp / .. - but those are native extensions.

FrankenPHP currently doesn’t have built-in support for statically linking external PHP extensions like those in Zend. One approach you might consider is integrating your extension directly into the Go side of the application as a function, which you can then expose as an API for PHP to call.
Alternatively, you could attempt using a shared library (*.so file), though this requires additional setup, possibly involving dynamic loading through dl() or similar methods. If that's not ideal, another option is to run your benchmark in an isolated PHP-FPM environment, where you know your Zend extension works, and then compare performance against FrankenPHP.

Yeah not sure, how is apcu / opcache and all the other extension doing it? They got a native support inside, and somehow it has to be possible, to add native support for my .so as well. The Go expose approach is way slower than anticipated and not the solution i am looking for, unfortunately.

FrankenPHP currently doesn’t support native linking of external extensions like .so files. The best option would be to run your benchmark in a PHP-FPM environment and compare the performance with FrankenPHP.
